# 'validate_inclusion_of' isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to set a condition where, if `my_counter` is equal to `0`, `1` or `2`, then my validation flag is set to `true`, otherwise set my validation flag to `false`.

But my `validate_inclusion_of` call isn't working:

```
if User.find_by_email(@email)
      user = User.find_by_email(@email)
      user.my_count += 1
      user.save

      # Here is where it fails
      if validates_inclusion_of :my_count, :in => [0,1,2]
        @my_flag = true
      else
        @my_flag = false
      end
```

Comment: You don't need to thank everyone for previous responses to previous answers; Be concise in your questions, and thank people by selecting their answer and/or upvoting those who've helped. And, contribute back to the community by helping answer other people's questions.

Comment: Have you read the [Rails validation documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)? Also, are you actually validating here, or just setting a value?

Answer (score 3):

That is not how you setup validations on models. May I suggest you do this:

```
@my_flag = [0,1,2].include? user.my_count
```

**Edit:** let me point out that you are finding your `User` twice which results in 2 queries. Consider doing this:

```
if user = User.find_by_email(@email)
  user.my_count += 1
  user.save
  @my_flag = [0,1,2].include? user.my_count
end
```

Comment: So my_flag is equal to 'true' if user.my_count has a value of 0, 1 or 2?  Yes?

Comment: Not only is that now how you set up a validation, you're also not even trying to validate anything. You just want to see if that value matches some other values.

Comment: @user1703974 you're welcome. Please accept this answer, and the answers of your other questions, if it worked for you. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Nice that you fixed the long-winded `if` that ended up converting a boolean to exactly the same boolean.